# SpringSourceToolSuite windows 7 32 bit installer is pointing to wrong JRE

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am trying to install SpringSourceToolSuite on windows7 32 bit machine and having an issue where springsource tool suite installer .exe file is looking for old jre and not to the new jdk, how can i make installer to point to new jdk instead of old jre?

Here is the error message that am getting:

> The Registry refers to non existent
>   Java Runtime Environment installatio
>   or runtime is corrupt. The system
>   cannot find the path specified.

Any suggestions?

Comment: is that after following my steps?

Comment: i have not reached to point where i can follow your steps, i have not been able to install springsource tool suite itself.

Comment: Have you downloaded the jdk and installed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Window>Preferences
2. Select Java from the list on the left, then Installed JREs
3. Click Add...
4. Select Standard VM
5. Point the JRE directory (Ex. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20) and give it a name and then click finish.[image]

Find your sts.ini file usually in the root directory, try adding this as the first line in the file, make sure it points to your jdk, also sometimes you need to put -vm and the path on different lines.

-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin\javaw.exe

You can also try using the zip installer instead of the .msi installer.

Comment: you are saying this steps to open in springsourcetoolsuite but am not able to install it altogether.

Comment: springtoolsuite is itself not getting installed, please see my question one more time.

Comment: so for this case sts installer would not work right, i have download zipped version and then find sts.ini file and make changes in that and then save it, is that correct?

Comment: Yes make the changes to the sts.ini file as i have specified, i'm trying to dig up my notes on the issue

Comment: i am still working on it, zipped file is still getting installed.

Comment: @kmb385 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1265/discussion-between-rachel-and-kmb385)

Comment: you have similar issue in the past

Comment: Yes, I am in the chat btw if you want to work on it in there it may be easier

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. This error means the entries for the java runtime in your windows registry point to a location that doesn't have java. This could mean a messed up Java installation (perhaps some Java version that wasn't properly uninstalled).

Perhaps this can be solved by re-installing Java (but I'm not 100% sure). Anyway, you can check the following steps to see if the registry is properly configured for a working Java installation.

(**CAUTION**: You gotta be careful when dealing with the registry and not modify unnecessary stuff)

1. Open the windows registry (Run -> regedit)
2. Navigate to the key **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment**
3. Check the value of the key "**CurrentVersion**". e.g. 1.6
4. On the tree view of the registry editor, click on the node inside "**Java Runtime Environment**" that has the same name as the value seen in above step. eg. 1.6
5. Check the value of the key "**JavaHome**" and "**RuntimeLib**". Check if these are valid paths.
6. If there are multiple versions listed in the tree view under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment**, then find out which version is working and has the paths properly configured.
7. You might have to change the value of the "**CurrentVersion**" (the key mentioned in Step 3). E.g, if the value there is 1.7, but your working Java installation is 1.6, and the node "1.6" has the correct paths (step 5), then change the value to 1.6

Hope you find this information useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having problems with the install program, make sure you have downloaded the entire file. Some days it may take awhile to complete. Check that the downloaded size is the same as that described, and run the hash program to check that it is intact

eg springsource-tool-suite-2.7.0.RELEASE-e3.7-win32-installer.exe  361MB   sha1 - md5

A partial download program may seem to start, but never completes. And it may not display any error message either  - as I learned, trying to do do an install too quickly  :)